# Check the axioms of the category of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I am working an elementary (not to me) exercise in category theory:

> Consider the category of sets, denoted by $\mathcal{S}et$. Check in detail the axioms of a category holds. What exactly are the morphisms?

I know that for each $A,B\in\mathcal{S}et$, we can define the set of morphisms $Mor(A,B)$ to just be the set of all the functions from $A$ to $B$.

However, I don't know how to prove the first axiom, that is

> If $A\neq C$ or $B\neq D,$ then $Mor(A,B)\cap Mor(C,D)=\varnothing$

I tried to argue with contradiction:

Let $A,B,C,D\in \mathcal{S}et$ such that $A\neq C$ and $B\neq D$, then consider $Mor(A,B)$ and $Mor(C,D)$.

Suppose $Mor(A,B)\cap Mor(C,D)\neq \varnothing$, then there must be a morphism $$f\in Mor(A,B)\cap Mor(C,D).$$

Then, we know that $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ and is also a function from $C$ to $D$.

Then what should I do to arrive at a contradiction? How could I use $A\neq C$ and $B\neq D$?

Thank you!

Comment: That depends on how you define what a function is. If your definition of function is the set-theoretic definition of a class of pairs, then the axiom is actually not satisfied. If your definition of function includes domain and codomain, then it is trivially fulfilled, etc.

Comment: @BenSteffan Oh my definition of function is the one that include domain and codomain. But then why trivial?

Comment: because then by definition, if $f$ is a function with domain $A$ and codomain $B$, it cannot also be a function with domain $C$ and codomain $D$ given that $A \neq C$ or $B \neq D$.

Comment: @BenSteffan oh!... okay I think I just forgot this kind of things for a long time. Thank you!

Comment: I think your statement of the axiom is wrong: it should read if $A \neq C$ **or** $B \neq D$.

Comment: @RobArthan oh yes. you right correct. It is just our professor gave us the axiom as $Mor(A,B)\cap Mor(C,D)=\varnothing$ unless $A\neq C$ and $B\neq D$. I tried to translate it to a nicer form, but I should use $or$. Thank you! (I will edit the post right away).

Comment: It's annoying that you have accepted an incorrect answer to this question.

Comment: @RobArthan It is definitely a mistake. I've never changed the acceptance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: you raise a good technical point. In a category, one must be able to determine the domain and codomain of an arrow from the arrow. If you take the usual set-theoretic approach and represent a function $f$ by its graph $\{(x, y) \mid f(x) = y\}$, then you cannot recover the codomain of $f$ from its representation: $n : \Bbb{N} \mapsto n^2$ could be viewed as function $\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$ or $\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}$. So you need to represent morphisms in the category of sets as pairs $(f, Y)$, where $f$ is the graph of a function whose range is contained in $Y$. (Or more symmetrically, you could use triples $(X, f, Y)$ where $f$ is the graph of a function from $X$ to $Y$.)

Comment: oh so that is why, as "Ben" pointed out in the comment, that I need to define the "function" as the domain-codomain thing, instead of a class of pairs. So I actually need to define the set of morphisms $Mor(A,B)$ to be the set of all functions $f$ with domain $A$ and codomain $B$. Right? Then the result follows.

Comment: You need to define $\mathsf{Mor}(A, B)$ to comprise the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ with each function equipped with enough information to recover $B$. So you need sets of pairs or triples to represents the morphisms as described above.

Comment: So for instance, $Mor(A,B)$ is the set of the graphs of all functions $g:A\longrightarrow B$, namely, if $f\in Mor(A,B)$, then $f=\{(x,g(x)):x\in A\}$ for some function $g:A\longrightarrow B$?

Comment: No. You have to represent the functions in a way that allows you to recover the codomain from the representation. So you need to take $\mathsf[Mor}(A, B)$ to be a set of pairs (or triples) giving you both the graph of the function and its codomain (and domain, for the sake of symmetry).

Comment: Oh! I get your point. okay. This makes sense.

Comment: So do you see now that the other answer is incorrect?

Comment: Yes. in that setting we cannot recover the codomain, as what you pointed out in the example you give. and it is indeed true that he was identifying $f$ with a graph, which is not generally true

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a relation $f\subset A\times B$ such that for all $x\in A$ there is exactly one $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$.

In your case, for $A\neq C$ and for any two morphisms $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:C\rightarrow D$ then $f\neq g$, or for $B\neq D$, then again $f\neq g$. Both cases imply that $Mor(A,B)\cap Mor(C,D)=\emptyset$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Thank you for your nice answer :)

Comment: Sadly, your answer won't work when the OP has corrected the question. See comments above.

Comment: well, that is why in my initial answer I only wrote that if $A\neq C$, then the intersection is empty. I will edit it anyway.

Comment: No, your answer still doesn't work: if $B \subset D$, then the graph of a function from $A$ to $B$ is also the graph of a function from $A$ to $D$. See my answer for a concrete example.

Comment: @RobArthan do you mean the graph of a function from $C$ to $D$? why?

Comment: I meant $A$ to $D$ (and have fixed the comment). I am assuming $A = C$ and $B \neq D$, which is the case in which the above answer doesn't work.

Comment: In order for two functions to be equal, the domain AND the codomain must be equal (among other things). Two functions with the same domain and images but with different codomains, are NOT the same functions!

Comment: No. The graph of a function does not give you enough information to recover the codomain.let $f = \{(n, n^2) \mid n \in \Bbb{N}\}$, then $f \subseteq \Bbb{N}\times \Bbb{N} \subseteq \Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{Z}$, so how can you tell whether the codomain of $f$ is $\Bbb{N}$ or $\Bbb{Z}$? In your answer, you say $f \subset A \times B$, so you are clearly identifying a function with its graph.

Comment: $f\subset A\times B$ means that the function has domain $A$ and codomain $B$. If two functions have either different domains, or different codomains, they are not the same functions.

Comment: In standard terminology $f \subset A \times B$ means $f$ is a subset of the cartesian product $A \times B$.

Comment: omg, can you please read my answer and the definition of a function?

Comment: Good lord! Can you please give a reference that justifies your interpretation of the assertion $f \subset A \times B$.

Comment: https://books.google.se/books?id=OXfmTHXvRXMC&pg=PA83&dq=%22function+is+a+relation%22&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22function%20is%20a%20relation%22&f=false

Comment: Thank you for that reference, but don't you see that that it does not preclude the possibility that a function from $A$ to $B$ is also a function from $A$ to $D$ where $D$ is a superset of $B$.

Comment: no. in this case even if the functions have the same image, they are not the same since they have different codomains.

Comment: The functions as represented in set theory as subsets of $A \times B$ are the same. The subset of $A \times B$ does not provide enough information to determine the intended codomain. Your reference supports this: you are reading "iff" where you reference says "if".

Comment: $f\subset A\times B$ means (for functions) $f:A\rightarrow B$ (i.e $B$ is not the image, but the codomain). For example the functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ and $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(n)=g(n)=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are different functions.

Comment: No. That is not the accepted meaning of $f \subset A \times B$. Your references don't justify your interpretation. The equation $f = g$ is true in set theory for your example.

Comment: No $f,g$ are not the same functions. have a look the wikipedia article about that. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)).

Comment: The Wikipedia article you cite states that *a function is uniquely represented by the set of all pairs $(x, f (x))$, called the graph of the function*.

Comment: It also says that "Two functions f and g are equal if their domain and codomain sets are the same and their output values agree on the whole domain".

Comment: Well, you and that part of the Wikipedia article are reading more into the set-theoretic representation of relations and functions than you are entitled to. I encourage you to raise your concerns with the good people who maintain the Wikipedia page.

Comment: so according to you, $f=g$ and therefore $f \in Mor(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N})\cap Mor(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$ ...

Comment: Yes. That's exactly right: the identity function on $\Bbb{N}$ is indistinguishable from the the injection of $\Bbb{N}$ into $\Bbb{R}$ in the standard representation of functions as sets of pairs in set theory.